# How to create SyncAdapter for multiple tables?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I have downloaded sample codes from android developer site of sample syncAdapter. It is syncing only one table and my problem is that i want to sync two tables(car and boat) from the sync adapter.

Answer (score 0):

`SyncAdapter` simply makes calls against a `ContentProvider` to update the local DB stored inside the `ContentProvider`.  In your calls to query or edit the tables, you provide a URI to the data.  The table name to be worked on is part of the URI, as explained in Android's [Content Provider Basics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) documentation.  As for the server side, that will be done with a URL to be fetched or posted to as well.